# json loads fails to load list of dictionaries

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am facing problem on loading list of dictionaries using `json.loads()`, error that i am getting is **TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'**.

here is my sample code that i am using

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    tasks = request.data['schedules']
    task_list = json.loads(tasks)
    print(task_list)
```

and this is request body that i am sending through postman raw JSON

```
{
"schedules": [
{"name":"A","job":{"minute" : "0",
      "hour" : "1"}},
  {"name":"B","job":{"minute" : "0",
      "hour" : "1"}}]
}
```

so here schedule is a field and it contains a list of dict as a value.

I have tried `json.dumps(tasks)` then `json.loads(tasks)` and also json.loads(tasks.decode("utf-8")) but getting same error.

Comment: It works perfect for me: https://repl.it/repls/IllStupidSearchservice

Comment: try printing type of tasks variable `print(type(tasks))`. if it is a list use `tasks = request.data['schedules'][0]`.

Comment: hi tried `print(type(tasks))` and i am grtting this `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the json first from the request data before using it like a dictionary:

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    tasks_list = data['schedules']
    print(tasks_list)
```

EDIT: apparently your request data is already a dictionary so:

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    tasks_list = request.data['schedules']
    print(tasks_list)
```

Comment: I tried this and i am getting error `the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'`

Comment: thanks for your quick response, the edited code is working fine for me.

Comment: It appears you are defining unreferenced `tasks_list` and printing undefined `task_list`